# What is the function equivalent of prepending the 'b' character to a string literal in Python 2?

Tags: python, string, binary

What function can I apply to a string variable that will cause the same result as prepending the `b` modifier to a string literal?

I've read in [this question about the `b` modifier for string literals in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269765/1663942) that prepending `b` to a string makes it a byte string (mainly for compatibility between Python 2 and Python 3 when using `2to3`).  The result I would like to obtain is the same, but applied to a variable, like so:

```
def is_binary_string_equal(string_variable):
    binary_string = b'this is binary'
    return convert_to_binary(string_variable) == binary_string

>>> convert_to_binary('this is binary')
[1] True
```

What is the correct definition of `convert_to_binary`?

Comment: `bytes(string_variable, 'utf-8')` ?

Comment: Is the assumption that strings are always encoded as utf-8 valid?

Comment: Yeah it is not universal. But it is the answer to your question title, If you know the encoding before hand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that in Python 2.x, the `b` prefix actually does nothing. `b'foo'` and `'foo'` are both exactly the same string literal. The `b` only exists to allow you to write code that's compatible with both Python 2.x and Python 3.x: you can use `b'foo'` to mean "I want bytes in both versions", and `u'foo'` to mean "I want Unicode in both versions", and just plain `'foo'` to mean "I want the default `str` type in both versions, even though that's Unicode in 3.x and bytes in 2.x".

So, "the functional equivalent of prepending the 'b' character to a string literal in Python 2" is literally doing nothing at all.

But let's assume that you actually have a Unicode string (like what you get out of a plain literal or a text file in Python 3, even though in Python 2 you can only get these by explicitly decoding, or using some function that does it for you, like opening a file with `codecs.open`). Because then it's an interesting question.

---

The short answer is: `string_variable.encode(encoding)`.

But before you can do that, you need to know what encoding you want. You don't need that with a literal string, because when you use the `b` prefix in your source code, Python *knows* what encoding you want: the same encoding as your source code file.* But everything other than your source code—files you open and read, input the user types, messages coming in over a socket—could be *anything*, and Python has no idea; you have to tell it.<sub>**</sub>

In many cases (especially if you're on a reasonably recent non-Windows machine and dealing with local data), it's safe to assume that the answer is UTF-8, so you can spell `convert_to_binary_string(string_variable)` as `string_variable.encode('utf8')`. But "many" isn't "all".*** This is why text editors and web browsers let the user select an encoding—because sometimes only the user actually knows.

<sub>* See [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for how you can specify the encoding, and why you'd want to..</sub>

<sub>** You can also use `bytes(s, encoding)`, which is a synonym for `s.encode(encoding)`. And, in both cases, you can leave off the `encoding` argument—but then it defaults to something which is more likely to be ASCII than what you actually wanted, so don't do that.</sub>

<sub>*** For example, many older network protocols are defined as Latin-1. Many Windows text files are created in whatever the OEM charset is set to—usually cp1252 on American systems, but there are hundreds of other possibilities. Sometimes `sys.getdefaultencoding()` or `locale.getpreferredencoding()` gets what you want, but that obviously doesn't work when, say, you're processing a file that someone uploaded that's in *his* machine's preferred encoding, not yours.</sub>

---

In the special case where the relevant encoding is "whatever this particular source file is in", you pretty much have to know that somehow out-of-band.* Once a script or module has been compiled and loaded, it's no longer possible to tell what encoding it was originally in.**

But there shouldn't be much reason to want that. After all, if two binary strings are equal, and in the same encoding, the Unicode strings are also equal, and vice-versa, so you could just write your code as:

```
def is_binary_string_equal(string_variable):
    binary_string = u'this is binary'
    return string_variable == binary_string
```

<sub>* The *default* is, of course, documented—it's UTF-8 for 3.0, ASCII or Latin-1 for 2.x depending on your version. But you can override that, as PEP 263 explains.</sub>

<sub>** Well, you could use the `inspect` module to find the source, then the `importlib` module to start processing it, etc.—but that only works if the file is still there and hasn't been edited since you last compiled it.</sub>

Comment: This is a great answer.  Thanks for going beyond what I specified in the question!  In fact, this more closely answers what I really wanted to know.  Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Note that in python 3.7, executed on linux machine, it is not the same to use `.encode('UTF-8')` and b'string' .
It cause a lot of pain in a project of mine and to this day I have no clear understanding of why it happens but doing this in Python 3.7

```
print('\xAD\x43\x48\x49\x44\x44\x49\x4E\x47\x53\x54\x4F\x4E\x45'.encode('UTF-8'))
print(b'\xAD\x43\x48\x49\x44\x44\x49\x4E\x47\x53\x54\x4F\x4E\x45')
```

returns this on console

```
b'\xc2\xadCHIDDINGSTONE'
b'\xadCHIDDINGSTONE'
```